Mismatch complier with kernel
While I was trying to install Virtual Box's Guest Additions, my Ubuntu's screen has been glitching, so I got 2 things to solve, but to no avail.
I read and applied from 3 "askubuntu" posts, the first is "This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules", where I used sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make perl dkms.
The second is "How do I install kernel header files?". I used both sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic, and sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r).
And the third is "Ubuntu 22.04 default GCC version does not match version that built latest default kernel", where I done sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-12, followed with sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc.
So, my current gcc version is now:
gcc (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
However, I still got the same error when running sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run.

VirtualBox Guest Additions: Reloading kernel modules and services currently loaded module vboxguest version () does not match to VirtualBox Guest Additions installation version (7.0.8 r156879)

From the /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log

Building the main Guest Additions 7.0.8 module for kernel 6.5.0-35-generic.


Error building the module.  Build output follows.


make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-35-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules


make1: warning: -j4 forced in submake: resetting jobserver mode.


warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel


The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0


You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0


make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1

I think I should done something obvious by now, but I'm too tired and annoyed with this glitches for hours. Thank in advance for anyone pointing out the next obvious step to fix this issue.

Usually the compiler version mismatch is just a warning, and doesn't cause the dkms build to fail - please add your current kernel version (uname -r) to the question and check the /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log again for actual errors - do you see any mention of strlcpy?

@steeldriver I'd updated the post, and there is no strlcpy found in the "vboxadd-setup.log".

All I can suggest is that you update your VirtualBox installation to a newer release and try installing the corresponding Guest Additions for that. Version 7.0.8 is over a year old now (the current release is 7.0.18), and according to the Changelog, "initial support for kernels 6.5 and 6.6" was only added in 7.0.12

Hi @K3nny_V4st I have the same problem now in Ubuntu 22.04, how did you end up solving this? thanks!

@Runsis Even I'm not sure how it was fixed. One day the problem resolved itself, but my gcc version was automatically downgraded back to 11.4.0, after I had updated both my VirtualBox and the VM's guest addition (aka Extension Pack) to 7.0.18.

thanks @K3nny_V4st i ended up uninstalling everything from Virtualbox but the VMs and then downloaded the latets version. Somehow the problem was fixed too. Although I had to stop using VMware cause I could not fix that one and stick to Virtualbox only
